# How to start Jboss Fuse as server

Tags: ubuntu, jboss, jbossfuse

I usally start Jboss fuse this way:

```
cd /opt/jboss-fuse/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-159/
bin/fuse
```

But when I close the terminal window then Fuse shuts down. So I need it to start like a server, preventing it from shutting down.

Its running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use bin/start to launch FUSE in server mode.

You may wanna check the doc here[1] to get more details

[1]https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/configuring_and_running_jboss_fuse/esbruntimestartstop

Freeman

Answer (score 1):

Starting JBoss Fuse is simple but it depends on your requirement.

**Make sure you have maven and java installed (versions which are acceptable for your JBoss Fuse version) on your machine and configure JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME environment variables.**

In its binary directory (bin) you can see some scripts or batch files with similar names.

If you are using Windows as an OS then use .bat files and in case of *nix based systems please use shell files.

Now different ways of starting fuse (For *nix systems):

1. Use ./fuse : It will start fuse instantly in foreground. As soon as you press Ctrl C you will be out from the command prompt of Fuse and your Fuse sever instance will be terminated.
2. Use ./start : It will start fuse in background. In case if you logout from current console, it won't impact your fuse instance.
3. Use ./client : It will connect you to the background instance of already running fuse.

Hopefully you will not face any issue.